# Trying to parse openweather api for json

Tags: javascript, android, json, openweathermap

I'm trying to parse the current api for openweathermap api. I'm am totally confused as to how to get the current data and the forecast information. Here is the json I am getting:

```
 "cod":"200",
"message":0.0074,
  "cnt":39,
"list":[
  {
     "dt":1534215600,
     "main":{
        "temp":293.24,
        "temp_min":292.346,
        "temp_max":293.24,
        "pressure":1021.77,
        "sea_level":1028.21,
        "grnd_level":1021.77,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":0.89
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":500,
           "main":"Rain",
           "description":"light rain",
           "icon":"10n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":20
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":2.51,
        "deg":275.001
     },
     "rain":{
        "3h":0.0050000000000008
     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 03:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534226400,
     "main":{
        "temp":292.3,
        "temp_min":291.706,
        "temp_max":292.3,
        "pressure":1020.99,
        "sea_level":1027.42,
        "grnd_level":1020.99,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":0.6
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":800,
           "main":"Clear",
           "description":"clear sky",
           "icon":"01n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":0
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":2.52,
        "deg":294.505
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 06:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534237200,
     "main":{
        "temp":291.07,
        "temp_min":290.77,
        "temp_max":291.07,
        "pressure":1020.65,
        "sea_level":1027.03,
        "grnd_level":1020.65,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":0.3
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":800,
           "main":"Clear",
           "description":"clear sky",
           "icon":"01n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":0
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":1.31,
        "deg":225.5
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 09:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534248000,
     "main":{
        "temp":293.286,
        "temp_min":293.286,
        "temp_max":293.286,
        "pressure":1020.78,
        "sea_level":1027.17,
        "grnd_level":1020.78,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":800,
           "main":"Clear",
           "description":"clear sky",
           "icon":"02d"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":8
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":2.83,
        "deg":234.501
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"d"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 12:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534258800,
     "main":{
        "temp":298.671,
        "temp_min":298.671,
        "temp_max":298.671,
        "pressure":1020.76,
        "sea_level":1027.15,
        "grnd_level":1020.76,
        "humidity":92,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":800,
           "main":"Clear",
           "description":"clear sky",
           "icon":"01d"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":0
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":2.71,
        "deg":259.5
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"d"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 15:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534269600,
     "main":{
        "temp":300.7,
        "temp_min":300.7,
        "temp_max":300.7,
        "pressure":1019.76,
        "sea_level":1026.18,
        "grnd_level":1019.76,
        "humidity":83,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":500,
           "main":"Rain",
           "description":"light rain",
           "icon":"10d"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":24
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":3.66,
        "deg":285.503
     },
     "rain":{
        "3h":1.11
     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"d"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 18:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534280400,
     "main":{
        "temp":298.464,
        "temp_min":298.464,
        "temp_max":298.464,
        "pressure":1019.68,
        "sea_level":1025.97,
        "grnd_level":1019.68,
        "humidity":83,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":500,
           "main":"Rain",
           "description":"light rain",
           "icon":"10d"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":48
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":3.27,
        "deg":289.504
     },
     "rain":{
        "3h":1.61
     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"d"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 21:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534291200,
     "main":{
        "temp":297.882,
        "temp_min":297.882,
        "temp_max":297.882,
        "pressure":1020,
        "sea_level":1026.37,
        "grnd_level":1020,
        "humidity":82,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":500,
           "main":"Rain",
           "description":"light rain",
           "icon":"10n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":36
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":2.37,
        "deg":275.004
     },
     "rain":{
        "3h":0.13
     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-15 00:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534302000,
     "main":{
        "temp":295.242,
        "temp_min":295.242,
        "temp_max":295.242,
        "pressure":1021.11,
        "sea_level":1027.53,
        "grnd_level":1021.11,
        "humidity":94,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":802,
           "main":"Clouds",
           "description":"scattered clouds",
           "icon":"03n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":32
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":1.26,
        "deg":313.002
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-15 03:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534312800,
     "main":{
        "temp":294.05,
        "temp_min":294.05,
        "temp_max":294.05,
        "pressure":1021.27,
        "sea_level":1027.77,
        "grnd_level":1021.27,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":800,
           "main":"Clear",
           "description":"clear sky",
           "icon":"01n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":0
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":2.46,
        "deg":274.504
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-15 06:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534323600,
     "main":{
        "temp":293.495,
        "temp_min":293.495,
        "temp_max":293.495,
        "pressure":1021.36,
        "sea_level":1027.7,
        "grnd_level":1021.36,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":800,
           "main":"Clear",
           "description":"clear sky",
           "icon":"01n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":0
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":3.01,
        "deg":277.505
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-15 09:00:00"
],
"city":{
  "id":4347778,
  "name":"Baltimore",
  "coord":{
     "lat":39.2909,
     "lon":-76.6108
  },
  "country":"US",
  "population":620961
```

}
}

Here is my attempted JSON. I'm only tryin to extract: temp, min_temp, max_temp, weather main, description and icon. 
Here is my attempted JSON parsing:

```
protected Weather[] doInBackground(String... params) {



    httpURL +=  "&q=" + cityName + apiKey;


    try {

        URL url = new URL(httpURL);


        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream());


        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);


        String inputLine;

        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();


        while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

            data.append(inputLine).append("\n");

        }


        bufferedReader.close();

        inputStreamReader.close();

        urlConnection.disconnect();


        Log.d("HTTP REQUEST", "SUCCESSFULLY COMMUNICATED WITH SERVER");


        return getResult(data.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.d("HTTP REQUEST", "FAILED TO RETRIEVE DATA FROM OPEN WEATHER");

        e.printStackTrace();

        return null;

    }

}


protected void onPostExecute(Weather result[]) {


}

public Weather[] getResult(String dataJSON) {

    if (dataJSON != null) {

        Log.d("HTTP REQUEST", dataJSON);

        Log.d("HTTP REQUEST", "SUCCESSFULLY RETRIEVED DATA FROM OPEN WEATHER ");


        try {

            JSONArray jsonRootArray = new JSONObject(dataJSON).getJSONArray("list");

            JSONObject jsonObject;

            JSONObject jsonObjectMain;

            JSONObject jsonObjectWeather;

            JSONObject jsonObjectTimeStamp;

            JSONArray jsonArrayWeather;


            Weather weatherData[] = new Weather[jsonRootArray.length()];


            for (int i = 0; i < jsonRootArray.length(); i++) {

                jsonObject = jsonRootArray.getJSONObject(i);

                jsonObjectMain = jsonObject.getJSONObject("main");

                String currentTemperature = jsonObjectMain.getString("temp");
                Double currentMinTemp = jsonObjectMain.getDouble("temp_min");
                Double currentMaxTemp = jsonObjectMain.getDouble("temp_max");
                Double currentHumidity = jsonObjectMain.getDouble("humidity");

                jsonObjectWeather = jsonObject.getJSONObject("weather");
                String weatherDescription = jsonObjectWeather.getString("description");
                String weatherIcon = jsonObjectWeather.getString("icon");

                String weatherTimeStamp = jsonObject.getString("dt_txt");


            }




            Log.d("JSON PARSE", "SUCCESSFULLY PARSED JSON");


            return weatherData;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.d("JSON PARSE", "FAILED TO PARSE JSON");

            e.printStackTrace();

            return null;

        }

    } else {

        Log.d("GET RESULT", "COULD NOT GET RESULT, VARIABLE IS <<NULL>>");

        return null;

    }

}
```

And here is my List class.

public class Weather {

```
private final String location;
private final String currentTime;
private final Double currentTemp;
private final Double maxTemp;
private final Double minTemp;
private final Double humidity;
private final String weatherDescription;
private final String weatherIcon;
private final String weatherTimeStamp;

public Weather(String defaultLocation, String defaultCurrentTime, Double defaultCurrentTemp,
               Double defaultMaxTemp, Double defaultMinTemp, Double defaultHumidity,
               String defaultWeatherDescription, String defaultWeatherIcon, String defaultWeatherTimeStamp) {

    location = defaultLocation;
    currentTime= defaultCurrentTime;
    currentTemp = defaultCurrentTemp;
    maxTemp = defaultMaxTemp;
    minTemp = defaultMinTemp;
    humidity = defaultHumidity;
    weatherDescription = defaultWeatherDescription;
    weatherIcon = defaultWeatherIcon;
    weatherTimeStamp = defaultWeatherTimeStamp;


}

// Get default Location
public String getDefaultLocation() {
    return location;
}

// Get default weatherCondition
public String getDefaultCurrentTime() {
    return currentTime;
}

// Get default windSpeed
public Double getDefaultCurrentTemp() {
    return currentTemp;
}

// Get default Humidity
public Double getDefaultMaxTemp(){ return maxTemp; }

// Get default Humidity
public Double getDefaultMinTemp(){ return minTemp; }

// Get default Humidity
public Double getDefaultHumidity(){ return humidity; }

// Get default Humidity
public String getDefaultDescription(){ return weatherDescription; }

public String getDefaultWeatherTimeStamp(){return weatherTimeStamp; }
```

Is my json parsing correct? I think its correct but I'm not sure.

Comment: Have you tried using GSON and POJO's to make your String->Object conversion a bit easier and cleaner?

Comment: I tried to validate your JSON response from json lint but it is showing a wrong response. May be this is the reason that why you facing problem.

Comment: I would like to do it with JSON parsing first to get it down if possible and it might not be validated because I didnt provide the api key? I just need to know if my JSON parsing is correct.